# not able to run Xamarin form app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am creating an app through *xamarin* by using *VS 2015*. Its created successfully but when I am going to run this app I am getting below error-
 `"aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819` 
I found this error on net and found that this is due to any "-" in any file name but in my solution there no file name with "-". I am totally frustrated with this error because I am not able to resolve from last 2 days . Please tell me about solution I don't want to waste my time more.
Please call me at 08171228040 if your support team can.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw0Ek.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall Android SDK and install it again from Visual Studio.

1. Uninstall SDK from - C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\uninstall.exe
2. Go to control Panel -> Uninstall a program - select Visual Studio
   (version) -> right click select -> Modify -> select SDK and install. It will take some time to complete installation.